# SHIFT+7 = ALT - bizarre behaviour

Tags: excel, keyboard-shortcuts

Suddenly, when using excel, SHIFT+7 has begun to produce the behaviour of the ALT-button in that it highlight my ribbon shortcuts. As SHIFT+7 is what I need to produce the character "/", this is a real annoyance. Keyboard layout is as it should be (Norwegian). Anyone knows if this is a bug, intended feature or an option I can somehow disable?

This is the only SHIFT-combination that creates this type of behaviour, and it only happens in Excel, not Word.

Getting ready for some "voted down" here, but this is has really baffled me, so have to ask.

Comment: Wrong site. This is not a programming question. Try superuser.com.

Comment: Not downvoting (perhaps I should...) but I think this would fit better in [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: @RaymondChen damn... 4 seconds late >.<

Comment: Yes, you should expect some down votes--so why not just ask the question where it belongs? http://superuser.com/

Comment: thanks, will move it. Did not know about SuperUser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design, the `/` acts like `Alt`. (Thay say it has something to do with Lotus compatibility.)

You can go to the Options, Advanced, find Lotus compatibility, and turn off this feature.

Comment: Thanks, I won't move it then, so you can get credit, but will refrain from asking such questions here in future. Did not know about SuperUser.